# What is the significance of the 'Version' column in Visual Studio NugetPackageManager interface? (as distinct from the 'Installed' column)

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, manage-nuget-packages

[image]

The 'Installed' column is populated, but the 'Version' column isn't.

What does the 'Version' column mean? (As distinct from the 'Installed' column)

*(I'm familiar with the concept of Semantic Versions; so I know exactly what the concept of a version number means for a nuget package. I'm asking for exactly what does *that* column in *that* interface mean.)*

---

*Follow-up question about blankness is over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795883/why-is-the-version-column-in-visual-studio-nugetpackagemanager-showing-blank-f).*

Comment: Relevant: [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning) on Microsoft Docs

Comment: Hmm - that page doesn't contain the information that I remember it doing. The "Version" column is the version that you'd install with the "Install" button; the "Installed" column is... what's currently installed.

Comment: `The "Version" column is the version that you'd install with the "Install" button` Hmmm that would make a lot of sense, as a way to design the UI ... but doesn't explain the behaviour in the screenshot :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Installed` should be easy to explain, when you choose a specific NuGet package, the version of this NuGet package will be listed in the `Installed` column, and only listing for the project(s) which has/have it installed. So if one project doesn’t install this NuGet package, then it will show blank.

Normally, the `Version` represents the same thing(`Installed`). First of all, the `Version` column should only display/list version number of the NuGet which is installed in/for .NET Standard, .NET Core or .NET projects, and for .NET Framework project it won’t list. This `Version` will match the version that set in the project’s project file(.xxproj file), even if the specific version(set in `.xxproj` file) of the NuGet package is not installed. But normally, it lists the same version number with `Installed` column.

For example(in .xxproj file):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="LochNessBuilder" Version="3.0.0-alpha" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So obviously, the `Version` column lists the version number of the NuGet packages which you are using(want to use), and the `Installed` column lists the version number of the NuGet packages which you have installed(or prepared to use, as maybe there exist multiple versions of the same NuGet package which were installed).

I think this can be **summarized** as:

1. If the specific version of NuGet package you have installed in the project, then the version number will be listed in `Installed` column, if not, it will be blank, and the `Installed` column is more likely to show that you have installed this version of NuGet package.
2. The version number listed in `Version` column matches the `Version` property setting in `.xxproj` file, and is more likely to show that you are using this version of NuGet package.
3. This two columns are usually show the same version number for one specific project.
4. .NET Framework based project will not list the version number in `Version` column. It will only list for .NET Core, .NET Standard and .NET project. The reason should be related to the different structures of these framework based project/project template, and the different mechanism of how to install/copy/store/use NuGet packages.
5. I believe this is not very important unless you see that they are different in two columns for one project.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've noticed (I can't find any references for it, maybe someone can add to it), but my experience has shown this:

When you're using the old Nuget `package.config` format for managing Nuget dependencies, it does NOT populate the `Version` field, just the `Installed` field.

When you switch over the new Nuget `PackageReference` format for managing nuget dependencies, then it populates the `Version` and the `Installed` fields.

If you're using a mix of the old `package.config` and `PackageReference` formats in your solution, the projects which are using `package.config` will only show the `Installed` field populated and those projects which use `PackageReference` will show both field populated.

Essentially it's a way for Nuget to tell you which format you're using in which project to manage nuget dependencies.

One way way to verify this, if you're using `package.config` for managing your Nuget packages, open Visual Studio options and change the default nuget preference to `PackageReference`. Now open a project which has multiple nuget packages installed, uninstall and reinstall one package and you'll notice that for that one package which is now managed using `PackageReference` it will show you the `version` field in addition to the `installed` field, where as the other packages still using the older `package.config` format, it will only show the `installed` field populated.