# Why is the 'Version' column in Visual Studio NugetPackageManager showing blank for .NET Framework projects?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, manage-nuget-packages

See pre-cursor question...
[What is the significance of the 'Version' column in Visual Studio NugetPackageManager interface? (as distinct from the 'Installed' column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795755/what-is-the-significance-of-the-version-column-in-visual-studio-nugetpackagema)

---

[image]

Having established that the Version column is intended to indicate "what version would be installed by clicking the install button now" ...

I'm testing .NET version compatibility of a Nuget Package that I'm publishing.
When I attempt to install it in't .NET Framework project, the 'Installed' column is populated, but the 'Version' column isn't.

- Why?
- What does the absence of a value in the column mean?
- Should I care / be worried? Have I done something wrong?

*I'm hoping this is just some artifact of Nuget having evolved along with the move from .NET Framework to .NET Core/Standard?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests, looks like the `Version` column is controlled by the `PackageReference` which is, of course, used in [new sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview) project.

I tried to migrate a project(.NET Framework) from `packages.config` to `PackageReference` and I saw that the `Version` column listed the version number this time.

So I think, if NuGet package manager can’t get/find the settings of PackageReference(should be in project file), then the corresponding `Version` column will be blank.

Even for a .NET Standard project, for example if you create a .NET Standard class library project, you can see that it includes `NETStandard.Library` package but at `Version` column it is blank and in its project file, `NETStandard.Library` is not set explicit(it should be included in sdk).

[image]