# What's the difference between Version and Installed in NuGet GUI in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've noticed that in Visual Studio's GUI for NuGet, the table showing which projects have a given package installed has the columns Version and Installed. Version always seems to either match what Installed says or is blank. For example, here's a screenshot after having just installed System.New.HttpJson to two projects.

[image]

Why does the last project have both columns populated, but the project before it has nothing in the Version column?

Comment: See answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795755/what-is-the-significance-of-the-version-column-in-visual-studio-nugetpackagema

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the significance of the 'Version' column in Visual Studio NugetPackageManager interface? (as distinct from the 'Installed' column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795755/what-is-the-significance-of-the-version-column-in-visual-studio-nugetpackagema)